# Updating listview after the user clicks item android

Tags: java, android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

i have an arraylist storing data from the database and display it in a listview, when the user clicks an item the data in the database is updated, i want to know how to refresh the items in the listview to show the updated data.

```
//Adding item to ArrayList
            Cursor cursor2=shoppingListDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ITEMS;", null);

            if  (cursor2.moveToFirst()){
                addArrrayList.clear();
                do{
                    String itemName = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("ITEM_NAME"));

                    addArrrayList.add(itemName);
                }
                while (cursor2.moveToNext());


                //====CODE FOR SHOWING DATA AS A SIMPLE LIST ITEM=========================================

                ArrayAdapter <String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addArrrayList);
                view_list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DATA NOT AVAILABLE", 3000).show();
            }
            cursor2.close();
```

here's my setOnItemClickListener code

```
view_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
    {
             String click = (addArrrayList.get(arg2).toString());
             String[] split = click.split("\\s+");
             String fSplit = split[0];
             String update = "UPDATE ITEMS SET FOUND = 'YES' WHERE ITEM_NAME =" + "'"+fsplit+"'";
            shoppingListDB.execSQL(update);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  " " + fSplit,3000).show();

    }

    });
```

how can i use `notifyDataSetChanged` to refresh the listview?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a simple way to clear your Arraylist which is an argument for Adapter. Fill it up again and calling notifyDataSetChanged.

```
addArrrayList.clear();
reFillYourArrayListWithUpdatedData(); /*first code part of your question*/
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Edit

I think the problem is about

```
shoppingListDB.execSQL(update);
```

row. You must use

```
public int update (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

instead of execSQL()

Here is docs;

[execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29)
[update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Comment: No the update in the database is successful, what i wanted was a way of getting the new updated data.

Comment: Could you edit your answer with, latest version of onItemClick block?

Comment: I give up, i've been sitting on my laptop for the past 12 hours, i'm just going to call the cursor every time the user clicks the item.